# Javascript - How does IF statement realize what you enter?

Tags: javascript

My If statement:

```
if (type = "connect") {
    window.open('games.html');
}
```

Hello everyone, I am really new to Javascript, and I can't find that information anywhere. At the top is my If statement for example. I want it to open for me a games tab when I type and press Enter the phrase "connect". But it works for everything that I typed. English isn’t my first language, so please excuse my mistakes. Thanks You.

Comment: Use `==` or `===` (comparison operator) instead of `=` (assignment operator)

Comment: `=` is an assignment and assigns a value `connect` to variable `type` then `type` is checked if is truthy which it is, so that `if` condition is always `true`.

Comment: you're using an assignment operator(=). use a compare operator(==).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `==` or `===` instead of `=`

= is assignment operator and others are comparison operators

Comment: This is literally a copy of @Satpal's comment..

Comment: show some effort by explaining what == and === will do and what is happening in OP's code with =

Comment: Oh, my bad. I will check my code more thoroughly before asking questions. Thanks you!